# What is the correct syntax to use when trying to create a Data Source View to a linked server?

Tags: linked-list, ssas, openquery

I have tried several statements but this one at least returns data.. but I get the error message: Deferred prepare could not be prepared. Incorrect syntax near')'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'. The following statement executed when creating namedquery:

```
SELECT[vwStatistics].*
FROM
(
***THIS IS MY QUERY***
DECLARE @SQL1  VARCHAR(500)
SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT     *
FROM OPENQUERY(PORTAL, ''SELECT DeviceID, Date, Count   
FROM printer_stats.Statistics
GROUP BY DeviceID'')' 
EXEC (@SQL1)
***END OF MY QUERY***
)
AS[vwStatistics] (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Controls)
```

I am new to linked servers and to SSAS. This is our company's first Cube from a linked server. My query does run in Management Studio and creates a SSRS report but it is slow. 
Any suggestions would be helpful. Not much info on syntax for this situation on web. I have been looking for any such situation and have not found much help other than trying changes on server. EX: Make sure openrowset is on and reinstall OWC component..  I do not have that capability.

Comment: This is what we found to work:SELECT DeviceID, CAST(statsdt AS CHAR) AS sdt, Count FROM OPENQUERY (PORTAL, 'select * from (select DeviceID,CAST( Date AS CHAR) statsdt, Count from printer_stats.Statistics) as pstats')

Answer (score 0):

This is what we found to work:

```
 SELECT DeviceID, CAST(statsdt AS CHAR) AS sdt, Count FROM OPENQUERY (
    PORTAL, 'select * from (select DeviceID,CAST( Date AS CHAR) statsdt, Count from printer_stats.Statistics) as pstats')
```